# roslaunch cannot find package

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a `.launch` file for a CAN bus reader, but roslaunch simple does not see it, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It is especially disconcerting as every other node I've got works just fine.

package.xml:

```
<package>
  <name>canbus_read</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  
  <description>Can_Bus_ROS_Reader</description>
  
  <maintainer email="bart.milne@pg.canterbury.ac.nz">Bart Milne</maintainer>
  <author>Bart Milne</author>

  <license>BSD</license>
   
  <url type="website"></url>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  
</package>
```

Launch file:

```
<!-- %Tag(FULL)%-->
<launch>
    <node name="candump" type="candump" pkg="canbus_read" output="screen" args="any" />
</launch>
<!-- %EndTag(FULL)%-->
```

The program's name is`candump`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171266/roslaunch-cannot-find-package/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to go about troubleshooting this is to see if it works with rosrun or not. You can start by trying:

```
rosrun canbus_read candump
```

If that doesn't work, you probably have a problem with your CMakeLists or your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH; make sure you've sourced your devel workspace, and make sure you're calling catkin_package() in your CMakeLists.txt (even if you call it with no arguments).

If it works with rosrun but not from a launch file, we can look for a more subtle root cause; maybe start by locating the binary and try to figure out why rosrun finds it, but roslaunch doesn't.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-05-28**:
Thanks, I will check that. I have a related question that includes the CMakeLists.txt. See http://answers.ros.org/question/171261/catkin_make-ignores-include_dirs-directive-in-catkin_generate_package/